# check if two rows are direct neighbours

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL Query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT team, sum(points) as allpoints FROM table WHERE [...] GROUP BY team ORDER BY allpoints";
```

Enetering it inside phpMyAdmin, I get the expected result. (and I see there is neither a duplicate in allpoints nor a duplictae in team!) 
Now I want to know, if the rows for two names are directly neighbour rows.
Therefore I did this:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$doCount=false;
$counter=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(strcmp($team1, $row['team'])==0 OR strcmp($team2, $row['team'])==0){
        $doCount=switchBool($doCount);
    }
    if($doCount){
        $counter++;
    }
}
if($counter < 2){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}   

function switchBool($thebool){
    if($thebool){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
}
```

Description: As soon as I catch one of the two teams, `$doCount` switches to `true` and my `$counter` increases to value 1. When I catch the second team, `$doCount` switches back `false` and `$counter` stop increasing. So if one team appears directly after the other team in my while-loop, `$counter` should only be `1` and it should return `true`. But it **always** returns true, even when I'm sure it shouldn't. What's my mistake?

Comment: just note, you can use `$doCount=!$doCount;` instead of `switchBool($doCount)`

Comment: Aren't you switching the bool every time the row has `$team1` or `$team2`?

Comment: yes. in the result there is no duplicte teamname

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're grouping on it, oh...you're not!

Comment: Uueerdo: I group, just forgot to write it here.

Comment: `$counter < 2` should be `$counter == 1`. You count the first team found, and shut off the counter if the other team is found next, before you count it. `<2` will return true if there is a one team gap between them as well.

Comment: Uueerdo: I really thought about it, but for my understanding, counter=2 if there is a one team gap between team1 and team2. But I changed to `$counter==1` and now it's alway false, even if it shouldn't be...

Comment: This is embarrassing: I thought several hours about it, but now I see: In my $sql I've had a variable which wasn't defined here =/ can be closed.